# Custom redirect after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, redirect

I have this form: http://lawb.co.il/HTMLPage.html

When someone click on the submit button `("שלח טופס" )` they are automaticaly redirected.

How can I prevent this action after clicking on the  `"שלח טופס"` button?

The code is here http://jsfiddle.net/TCpkb/4/

Can you help me with it pleas?

Comment: [Please include the relevant code in the qustion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114942/153691). If the external site goes down, the question here on StackOverflow is not nearly as valuable.

Answer (score 2):

instead of `input type="submit"` use

```
<input type="button" value"submit" onclick="dothis()"/>

<script>
function dothis(){
//do whatyever you want
//for example for custom redirect :-
window.location.href="www.google.com";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried and it works, but now I dont get the email with all the details that user fill in the form, why?

Answer (score 0):

1. your HTML is not formatted in your given link have a two form tag (one form tag inside another ) check you html first
2. in your form `action="http://www.emailmeform.com/builder/form/VaHUixmgcX0Qd0BO1a4ho"` so obviously your page redirect to action url

please do some homework

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp you can find here a sample .